# Do any body knows how to create a "Run/Remote" Configuration IntelIj to connect wildfly server,please let me know

Tags: intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I want to create a "Run/Remote" Configuration IntellIj to connect remote wildfly server running in Ubuntu the code is in Intellij in windows,want to debug,please let me know

I have created a Remote Gradle task in Intellij,and imported and builded the WAR file project in Linux,then i started wildfky server in linux & i run the gradle task in Intellij,although when i click the debug gradle task all the threads are instantiated & debug is suddenly stopping in Intellij without any breakpoint hit in Intellij IDE[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NcwY.png)

Comment: What is your "remote-gradle" task? What IDE version do you use?

Comment: Am using IntelliJ Ultimate 2018 version

Comment: Could you please share project example or describe what "remote-gradle" task you use?